# The second uniqueness theorem in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

Does the second uniqueness theorem just say that if there is an electric field that satisfies Gauss's law for a surface surrounding each conductor + a surface of elnclosing all the conductor, it is indeed the true electric field, and no other electric field will satisfy those conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting this! I myself had a doubt that I couldn't resolve until I saw the theorem put this way.
Still, what you said needs some important corrections/additions..

It actually proves (not 'state'!, I'll tell why in the next paragraph) that:

*If there is a **solution of** electric field that:*
*1) satisfies Gauss's law for the surface surrounding each conductor + a surface "S" enclosing all the conductors, **with S itself being bounded by a 'single' conductor OR is unbounded (i.e. S is at infinity where electric potential is constant)**.*
***2) satisfies $$ \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{F} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$ in the volume jammed between S and the  the interior conductors, call it "$\mathcal{V}$" (Here $\rho$ is the charge density in $\mathcal{V}$).***
*Then it is the only possible electric field **for $\mathcal{V}$**, and no 'other' solution of electric field will satisfy these two conditions.*

The only major additions I made here is regarding the outer boundary and point number 2, (and other words in bold) and these are important.

The actual statement is that (I'm stating it your way, not as in Griffiths):

*If a solution of electric field satisfies:*
*1) Gauss's law on all the surfaces (interior and exterior) of a volume $\mathcal{V}$, with the $\mathcal{V}$'s each surface bounded by a conductor.*
*2) Satisfies $ \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{F} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$ in $\mathcal{V}$.*
*Then it is the only possible electric field for $\mathcal{V}$, and no 'other' solution of electric field will satisfy these two conditions.*

The difference between this and the previous statement is that, the latter one is more general as for example, there can be cases where $\mathcal{V}$ is the whole of space with no (bubbles of) conductors anywhere (which is a very trivial example, though you can make other examples).

Comment: Thank you! I really needed this! Because otherwise it's not clear how one is supposed to make use of the theorem. Also thank you for adding that the outer boundary needs to be at a constant potential, because this was also causing me somd trouble as I wanted to theorem to be general, but the proof explicitly used the constancy of potential to derive the result!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that I helped you too ;)